# Would someone provide an example of Rest API call with user authentication and arguments passed in Robot test framework

Tags: api, authentication, robotframework

The Get, Get request key words in requests library documentation does not provide any examples where user credentials/AUTH_TOKEN and other arguments passed in the API call.

Comment: which robotframework library are you using? Also, have you done any research before asking? Assuming you're using RequestsLibrary, there are lots of examples in its own test suite. https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/tests/testcase.txt

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  I ran test using the first example from the link you posted and I get error No keyword with name 'Create Session' found.
No keyword with name 'Delete All Sessions' found. I am quite new to this framework and honestly this is the first test I am trying out in this framework.

Comment: Please tell us which robot library you're using. It sounds like you're not using RequestsLibrary.

Comment: I am using both Collections and  RequestsLibrary.

Comment: And copy pasted the 'Get Requests' test case from github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/tests/…examples.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong if you're getting an error about `Create Session not found`, since that keyword is created by that library. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

As Bryan pinted, the examples  are in the libraries tests.

For basic authentification, there is:

```
Get With Auth
   [Tags]  get     get-cert
   ${auth}=  Create List  user   passwd
   Create Session    httpbin    https://httpbin.org     auth=${auth}   verify=${CURDIR}${/}cacert.pem
   ${resp}=  Get Request  httpbin  /basic-auth/user/passwd
   Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}  200
   Should Be Equal As Strings ${resp.json()['authenticated']} True
```

If you get *No keyword with name 'Create Session' found.*, that means that you are not importing the library correctly or not having it installed correctly.

If you just running the *testcase.txt*, **wrong import** is the most like reason. It imports the keywords **directly from the source file in author's local repository**, instead of installed library package:

```
Library ../src/RequestsLibrary/RequestsKeywords.py
```

Instead, import it like in the examples in the librarie's GIT homepage/readme.MD

```
Library     RequestsLibrary
```

If there is issue with installation, just do:

```
pip install -U requests
pip install -U robotframework-requests
```

Comment: Thanks Jan and Bryan -  The issue was with the Library installation on our network. I had to re-install out-side-of my office network for a successful install.